# How to change part of an inline SVG's appearance when hovering over another outside source div or text element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have been looking for an HTML/CSS only solution to this issue for about 2 weeks now and nothing has come from any research or experimentation. I have come to the understanding that this is not possible with CSS so I was wondering if anyone could provided me a Javascript example that could possibly work for my case as javascript isn't my strong suit at the moment. My issue is that I have a multi-component SVG element. It is inline in the HTML and within a section tag. There is also a set of text elements in the section above the SVG. What I am trying to make happen is that when a portion of the SVG is hovered, the corresponding text element and the hovered SVG piece both change color. Vice versa if the text element is hovered, the corresponding SVG piece will change color as well.

```
<section>

<h1>Section 1</h1><h1>Section 2</h1>

<svg id="World_Map"...<path class="_russia_"...</svg>

</section>
```

It is probably important to note that the SVG has multiple paths with unique ID's and these are the pieces that I am trying to get working in this fashion.

Comment: You should try making a jsfiddle, or codepen, which has your example code. This will allow people to modify what you have so far! :) https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, without the SVG elements being siblings or ancestors to your text elements this is very difficult (if not impossible) to do with CSS. I have seen some pretty tricky and amazing things done with CSS selectors, though, so I wouldn't rule it out that someone more clever than me could get it to work. :)

Anyway, I have a working example of what you asked for using JavaScript. It actually makes use of jQuery because there is the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) binding, which cleanly allows you to bind a single function to the mouseenter and mouseleave events simultaneously, and the [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method, which will add a class to an element if it doesn't exist or remove the class from the element if it's already there.

Since you did not post any functional code, here is a JSFiddle with my simple example.

https://jsfiddle.net/davecripps/o6mwjokj/

```js
$(function() {
  $("h1").hover(function() {
    $("#map" + $(this).attr("id").substring(4)).toggleClass("mapHover");
  });

  $("rect").hover(function() {
    $("#text" + $(this).attr("id").substring(3)).toggleClass("textHover");
  });
});
```

```css
.textHover,
h1:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mapHover,
rect:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h1 id="textRussia">Russia (yellow)</h1>
  <h1 id="textSpain">Spain (blue)</h1>
  <h1 id="textFrance">France (green)</h1>
  <svg width="340" height="100" viewbox="0 0 340 100">
    <rect id="mapRussia" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow" />
    <rect id="mapSpain" x="120" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
    <rect id="mapFrance" x="240" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="green" />
  </svg>
</section>
```

You should be able to understand the methodology and apply to your code.